# UIImagepicker disappears immediately aftershowing on iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uiimagepickercontroller

I have 2 Storyboards for iPhone and iPad. 
From a Button on a UITableviewcontroller I want to select an Image with a UIImagepicker.

On the iPad this works fine, on the iPhone the UIImagepicker is shown for very short moment and then he disappears.

The calling code is the same for iPad an iPhone and as I can see the storyboards are idenitical. Im looking for hours and cannot see why the Imagepicker disappears on iPhone and on iPad not.
Has anyone an idea for this behaviour? What can be the reason why the UIImagePicker disappears without doing anything?

```
- (void) go {
    UIImagePickerController *ipc = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
    [ipc setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum];
    ipc.delegate=self;
    [self presentViewController:ipc animated:YES completion:^{}];
    }
- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker{
    NSLog(@"imagePickerControllerDidCancel");
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{}];
    }

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    [self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{}];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{}];
        NSLog(@"didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo");
    }
```

On iPhone the log "imagePickerControllerDidCancel" is never shown!

Comment: Show some code!  Have you stepped through with the debugger, and/or taken out other code to see if you can minimize the problem?

Comment: Declare this  `UIImagePickerController *ipc` as a property, instead of local variable

Answer (score 0):

Store the picker in a strong class property instead of a local variable, like this:

`@property(nonatomic, strong) UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController`

...

```
- (void) go {
    self.imagePickercontroller = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
    self.imagePickercontroller.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
    self.imagePickercontroller.delegate=self;
    [self presentViewController:ipc animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: No, the same result. I think it has something to do with the storyboard(s) because on the iPad the code rus perfect and on the iPhone not... tx